# VB.NET Try Catch block issues

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

The program I need to complete is focusing on the try catch blocks. The problem I am having is that the error message is shown every time the user tries to input anything, even valid numeric data. I've been trying to figure it out for the past few hours, maybe someone can see my mistake...

```
Private Sub CalculateButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalculateButton.Click
    'Convert input values to numeric variables.
    Dim SnowboardInteger, WithBootsInteger, TotalInteger As Integer

    Try
        'Convert snowboard to numeric variable.
        SnowboardInteger = Integer.Parse(SnowboardsTextBox.Text)

        Try
            'Convert with boots if snowboard was sucessful.
            WithBootsInteger = Integer.Parse(WithBootsPriceTextBox.Text)

            'Calculate the total price.
            TotalInteger = SnowboardInteger + WithBootsInteger

            'Calculate summary values.
            SnowboardSumInteger += SnowboardInteger
            WithBootsSumInteger += WithBootsInteger
            TotalSumInteger += TotalSumInteger
            SaleCountInteger += 1
            AverageInteger = TotalSumInteger / SaleCountInteger

            'Format and display price values.
            SnowboardsPriceTextBox.Text = SnowboardInteger.ToString("c")
            WithBootsPriceTextBox.Text = WithBootsInteger.ToString("c")
            TotalPriceTextBox.Text = TotalInteger.ToString("c")

            'Format and display summary values.
            SnowboardRentalTextBox.Text = SnowboardSumInteger.ToString()
            WithBootsRentalTextBox.Text = WithBootsSumInteger.ToString()
            TotalChargesTextBox.Text = TotalSumInteger.ToString()
            AverageChargeTextBox.Text = AverageInteger.ToString()

        Catch Snowboards As FormatException
            'Handle a snowboard exception.
            MessageBox.Show("Snowboards value must be numeric.", "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            With SnowboardsTextBox
                .Focus()
                .SelectAll()
            End With
        End Try

    Catch WithBoots As FormatException
        'Handle a with boots exception.
        MessageBox.Show("Snowboards with Boots value must be numeric.", "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        With WithBootsTextBox
            .Focus()
            .SelectAll()
        End With

    Catch AnException As Exception
        'Handle any other exceptions.
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & AnException.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use `Try-Catch` to handle invaild data, use `Int32.TryParse` instead. Don't use `Catch` for normal workflow at all. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/107727 It's just for _exceptional_ situations.

Comment: You have all the code in one or both blocks, so your MsgBox will report a numeric error even if the actual problem is something in your code NOT having to do with numeric entry.  Teh exceptions themselves will tell you what the error is if you look.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I've it figured out, and thank you also for a timely response :)